# Settings.bundle ... why can't my code access the values via [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults, settings.bundle

I don't understand the logic:

When I create a settings bundle the values are nil when accessed from code via

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"mykey1"]
```

But as soon as I touch this key via the  Settings.app this key is readable by my code.

Solutions I found require to read the file "Root.plist", build a dictionary from it, `register` the values and `synchronize` them.

I read the Apple docu multiple times - I still do not understand the idea and the standard pattern for delivering an app with a set of standard settings.

Any hints for my studies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existence of a Settings.bundle does not have any effect on `NSUserDefaults`. It's not until a value is changed from its default that the value is reflected in `NSUserDefaults`.

The proper solution is to use `NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:`. In many cases, you load the dictionary of defaults with the contents of the `Root.plist`. You do not need to call `synchronize` for this. The defaults get registered every time your app runs. The values are not actually stored. When you ask for a value from `NSUserDefaults`, if no explicit value exists, then the registered defaults are looked at for a value.

You should register the defaults as soon as possible at app startup.

Comment: Thanks! I am still confused: why doesn't Apple offer at least the option that the app uses the Settings.bundle as defaults? Is there a standard implementation for this task? I have seen a couple and they do not look equal, so any recommendations here?